# What is the maximum speed an ion engine can propel a spacecraft at?

Tags: spacecraft, propulsion, probe, power

I read that with our current ion propulsion technology it is possible we could send a craft moving the maximum of 100km per second, or around 62 miles.
However we seem to be limited by how strong of a power generator we are able to put aboard the craft.. Is it possible that with enough power we could accelerate a spacecraft beyond this 100km per second limit? What is the maximum speed we could send a craft moving in space at with our current ion engine technology?

Comment: (0.999999...)c.

Comment: @Erik Not without fantasy engineering.

Comment: But it is possible with current technology.

Comment: @Erik It's really not -- see my answer.

Comment: So it was just a comment, not a serious answer.  Having said that, the OP never restricted the answer to a single stage launch, nor did they say how big the spacecraft is.  Your engine lifetime point is a good one however, but in the end, it just more dry mass on a _very_ big vehicle.

Comment: Also, to your point, the T. equation doesn't account for relativistic effects -- which makes it even more difficult.

Comment: You run out of Xenon on the planet long before you need to worry about relativistic speeds.

Comment: Why are limited to Xenon on the planet?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/61337/discussion-between-russell-borogove-and-erik).

Comment: Let me ask, if we send a probe into vicinity of Kuiper Belt, then lose the 4.7km/s or so of orbital speed and let it drop like a rock into the Sun, what will its speed be before it's incinerated?

Comment: ...100km/s is the escape speed of solar system from a 38 solar radii altitude above Sun. Probes can definitely survive that. So yeah, lob the probe into Kuiper belt, arrest the orbital speed, give a bit of a kick towards the Sun (otherwise the beginning will take ages) and let it take the plunge. You'll get ~600km/s before it impacts the surface.

Answer (score 20):

The limit isn't due to power, but to engine lifetime and fuel limits.

Ion engines produce very little thrust, so in order to reach speeds of 100km/s they must accelerate continuously for months or years. The [Dawn](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dawn_(spacecraft)) spacecraft, for example, was built with three redundant [ion thrusters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NASA_Solar_Technology_Application_Readiness) to extend its lifetime, and got nowhere near 100km/s; it carried enough propellant to change its speed by about 10km/s, and took [15000 hours (~1.7 years) of continuous thrust to change its speed by 4.3km/s](https://www.space.com/8579-nasa-spacecraft-breaks-speed-boost-record.html).

To achieve a [∆v](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delta-v) of 100km/s with an ion engine like those on Dawn (with a specific impulse of 3100 s (exhaust velocity of 30400 m/s)) we turn to the [Tsiolkovsky rocket equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tsiolkovsky_rocket_equation):

$$\Delta v = v_\text{e} \ln \frac {m_0} {m_f}$$

Where $v_\text{e}$ is the rocket exhaust velocity and ${m_0}$ and ${m_f}$ are the mass of the craft full of fuel and empty respectively.

$$100000 = 30400 \ln \frac {m_0} {m_f} \Rightarrow 3.29 = \ln \frac {m_0} {m_f} \Rightarrow  \frac  {m_0} {m_f} = e^{3.29} = 26.8$$

So an ion-thruster spacecraft intending to reach 100km/s must carry 26 times its dry mass in xenon propellant. This is an extremely high mass ratio, not generally achievable in a single-stage spacecraft. A two- or three-stage spacecraft could do it with reasonable mass ratios.

Ion engines are already very power-hungry, and need to be paired with a lot of mass in solar panels or [RTGs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radioisotope_thermoelectric_generator). More powerful thrusters could increase the exhaust velocity by a small amount, driving down the mass ratio, but at the cost of greatly increasing the dry mass with the larger power supply.

Note that I'm referring to a *change in speed* or ∆v throughout this answer, rather than a maximum speed. This is because the speed of objects in space must be described relative to a particular reference point, and speed limits don't work the way they do for Earth-bound vehicles.

Comment: It's a bit of a nitpick, but shouldn't that be $\Rightarrow$ (`\Rightarrow`) rather than $\rightarrow$ (`\rightarrow`)? The first time I read this, I read $\rightarrow$ as $\to$ (the "goes to" operator; in LaTeX, `\to`).

Comment: @MichaelKjörling Thank you -- it looked wrong to me but I wasn't sure if there was a formal convention. `\rightarrow` was the first thing I tried that looked vaguely useful.

Comment: I don't know if it's *formally correct*, but it is what I learned back in school.

Answer (score 5):

You have it correct, but you are looking at a very narrow range of ISP.

- The BepiColombo mission to mercury uses an ion thruster with a ISP of 4,200 seconds(41,202 M/s). The same formula yields a mass ratio of 11.325.
- The NEXIS ion thruster can achieve 8000 seconds (78,200 m/s)
- The European DS4G innovative thruster manages 19,300 seconds (188,200 m/s) exceeding the 100 km/sec from the above question.
- Lithium fed GIT (gridded ion thrusters) have demonstrated 50,000 - 80,000 seconds of ISP(490 km/s to 780 km/sec).

The problem is not so much mass ratio but power applied to the thruster and electrode erosion. The DS4G is the first thruster to have concentrated power in a small form, what is needed a nuclear reactor delivering 100 of KW's or maybe Mw of power.

With Megawatts of power it is possible to have Ion thrusters exceeding 100,000 seconds of ISP (over 1,000 km/sec).

Comment: `+1` I've just asked [What is a Lithium fed GIT? How does it work?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/40958/12102)