# Orbit transfer trajectory options to the moon

Tags: orbital-maneuver, cubesat, flyby, gmat

I am working on a project for a lunar flyby using a CubeSat. I was wondering what kind of trajectory transfer options are present and which one would be best for a CubeSat? I'm aiming for a transfer from either 400km LEO or GTO to a 100km Low Lunar Orbit.

EDIT

After doing some research on electric propulsion engines, I've finalised on using the MiXi thruster. I have been working on simulating this on GMAT, right now I am able to get a flyby at a very high altitude (3590 km) which is definitely not enough. Additionally, I have been trying to perform the flyby near Mare Tranquilititus. The GMAT tutorials do cover this problem, however, they're using a plugin called VF13ad, which I have not been able to figure out how to install and run on my PC.

Comment: Flyby or Orbit? starting from GTO should be easier. You'd probably be looking at a trajectory like that used for Chandrayaan-2

Comment: What's about communication to and from a cubesat over such a long distance from Earth to the Moon? Increasing communication distance by a factor of 1000 (from 400 to about 400000 km) is not easy.

Comment: What's about the neccessary fuel for lunar orbit insertion? Does it fit into the cubesat? Low lunar orbits may be instable due to lunar mascons.

Comment: Are you sticking with some absolute design limits for a "Cubesat," such as total fuel/thrust capability, or are you just using a generic term for a small satellite?

Comment: you would need almost all the space to be fuel

Comment: Hi @BruceVici If you have two accounts (new registered and old unregistered) and would like to merge them into one account, there is a standard process for that.

Answer (score 1):

there's effectively none. 
Hypergolics are not allowed in cubesats, and delta-v req. LEO->LLO is 4 and 8 km/s (high-thrust low-thrust)
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delta-v_budget

So, spec it for moonlaunch rideshare, if possible.

You might want to have a look at Cornell university electrolysis solution:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cislunar_Explorers
https://cislunarexplorers.wordpress.com/

There's an excellent article of their cubesat configuration (and required lightweight astronav solution) on IEEE AESS magazine volume 34, number 9, september 2019:
Contents: https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/stamp/stamp.jsp?tp=&arnumber=8826567
Purchase: https://resourcecenter.aess.ieee.org/publications/aess-electronic-magazine/AESSMAG0380.html

Interesting subject. Hope that you can find a solution that works for you.

HTH,
PF

Comment: Answers to [Going from LEO to lunar using only low-thrust ion propulsion - can it be done?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/28037/12102) suggest that a 3U cubesat with a sizable fraction of its mass being say liquid krypton or xenon could do it, though that might be considered too much stored energy so maybe iodine or lithium? [1](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/16616/12102), [2](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/40958/12102), [3](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/39839/12102), [4](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/28033/12102)

Comment: Yes, but your linked question refers to SMART-1, which was launched to GTO. My point was that for a 3-6U cubesat, intended to have a meaningful mission payload, self-transfer from LEO to LLO is beyond capability of current ion systems.